# Img src in Storage link using v-for not working in Laravel vuejs

Tags: php, laravel, image, vue.js

I created the image directory using `php artisan storage:link` but when I tried calling the image `src` inside the `v-for` it doesn't display anything at all.

When I tried the static URL, it works-

```
<img width="300px" v-else src="{{ url('storage/images/validations/20221013192153-cvd-card-image-160310009-0155-00161.png') }}" alt="Red dot"  />
```

But when I tried this in a for loop, it was not working.

```
<div class="custom"  v-for="(emv, index) in emvdetailsdata" :key="emv.evd_id">
 <img width="300px" v-else src="{{ url('storage/images/validations/emv.card_image') }}" alt="Red dot"  />
</div>
```

I also tried, `:src`, but nothing worked.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I dont get it, are you trying to validate the image path from vue? and of course the first example will work because you are going to a direct path. But the 2nd example is doing what exactly?

Comment: @KGG Im trying to call the response data from the database which is called by `v-for` and inside v-for I have `emv.card_image` which is the name of the image file I tried but it doesn't view the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass the variable like this:

```
 <img :src="'/storage/images/validations/'+emv.card_image" />
```